# Doubt :: my sql performance tuning

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL performance tuning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29144/mysql-performance-tuning)

I would like to optimize my MySQL DB and I identified some important points as follows:

1. enabling query cache,
2. using memory storage (I know pros and cons of this, but since I have static tables, I need not worry about this facilities drawback. Before execute query I'll check if memory table exists or not.)
3. increasing `key_buffer_size`

My question is: Can I use both query cache and memory storage? Also, what is the role of `key_buffer_size`?

Why I am asking? Because everything depends on system memory. How these three options will work together? Can I do these things together?